# AugPake implementation Doubt K computation

Tags: prime-numbers

try to implement the [AugPake protocol](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-shin-tls-augpake-07) in java using `BigInteger`.

I am having some difficulty computing $K=Y^z \mod p$ because $z$ is always $0$, for $z={1\over x+(w*r)} \mod q$. Being a ratio between $1$ and a very large number $z$ will be always zero using the `BigInteger`.

Can help me to understand how to compute $z$? Maybe I misunderstood some of the document.

---

Thanks for your reponse.

To compute Z i use the extended Euclidean algorithm:
ax + qy = gdc(a,b)

Thanks a lot

Comment: Please note that the BigInteger.modInverse function, as most BigInteger-methods, does not run with constant time, so your implementation will be vulnerable to timing attacks.

Answer (score 3):

**This is not ordinary real-valued division.**

The computation you are looking at is done in the field $\mathbb F_q$ instead of $\mathbb R$, that is $1/x$ actually is the [*modular multiplicative inverse*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) of $x\bmod q$.